# How to scroll according to our needs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, division

I have a fixed header which makes a small amount of div behind the header. So I want to scroll to the `#services` div but with `-100px` scroll and the following code is what I am currently using. How would I go about subtracting `100px` in the following lines of code:

```
$(".menu-services").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#services").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: So you are asking how to subtract 100?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code:

```
$(".menu-services").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#services").offset().top - 100
    }, 2000);
});
```

And to make it more dynamic, let us say that your header id is `fixed-header` then you can write:

```
$(".menu-services").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#services").offset().top - $('#fixed-header').outerHeight()
    }, 2000);
});
```